# Python / lxml: Nested for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, lxml, nested

I've got some XML that I'm trying to parse. Example:

```
<TVAMain>
    <ProgramDescription>
        <ProgramLocationTable>
            <Schedule value1="1234">
                <ScheduleEvent>
                    <Program value2="1234567890" />
                </ScheduleEvent>
                <ScheduleEvent>
                    <Program value2="1234567891" />
                </ScheduleEvent>
            </Schedule>
            <Schedule value1="5678">
                <ScheduleEvent>
                    <Program value2="1234567892" />
                </ScheduleEvent>
                <ScheduleEvent>
                    <Program value2="1234567893" />
                </ScheduleEvent>
            </Schedule>
        </ProgramLocationTable>
    </ProgramDescription>
</TVAMain>
```

I am trying to retrieve all entries of value1, and all entries of value2, and output them in a file as value1|value2.  I can successfully get value 1 or value 2 to write out to a file, but I can't get them at the same time!

This is my code so far (I've ditched the writing step for the time being, just trying to get it to print out both bits of data first):

```
from lxml import etree

parser = lxml.etree.XMLParser()


tree = lxml.etree.parse(file_name, parser)
root = tree.getroot()

nsmap = {'xmlns': 'urn:tva:metadata:2010'} 

with codecs.open(file_name+'.log', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for info in root.xpath('//xmlns:Schedule', namespaces=nsmap):
         value1 = (info.get('value1'))
         print (serviceid)
         for info in root.xpath('//xmlns:Schedule[@value1 = "value1"]/ScheduleEvent/Program', namespaces=nsmap):
               value2 = (info.get('value2'))
               print (crid)
```

This code will successfully print all of the 'value1' values but no value2.

I have tried the following:
 - using 'info2' in the second for loop
 - playing around with the second xpath, entering known values for value1

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Yep, sorry.  It was a typo

Answer (score 1):

Working with the XML you posted, you could find all the values with one XPath:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

tree = ET.parse('data')
tree.xpath('//Schedule')  

values = tree.xpath('//Schedule/@value1 | //Schedule/ScheduleEvent/Program/@value2')
for vals in zip(*[iter(values)]*3):
    print(vals)
```

prints

```
('1234', '1234567890', '1234567891')
('5678', '1234567892', '1234567893')
```

This XPath assumes there is always one `value1` attribute followed by two `value2` attributes. If you don't want to rely on that assumption, then you could instead loop this way:

```
for schedule in tree.xpath('//Schedule[@value1]'):
    value1 = schedule.get('value1')
    print(value1)
    for value2 in schedule.xpath('ScheduleEvent/Program/@value2'):
        print(value2)
```

---

In your code:

```
root.xpath('//xmlns:Schedule[@value1 = "value1"]/ScheduleEvent/Program', namespaces=nsmap)
```

did not work because `"value1"` is a literal string. You would need to replace that with the variable `value1`:

```
'//xmlns:Schedule[@value1 = "{v}"]/ScheduleEvent/Program'.format(v=value1)
```

Although while that would work, specifying the `value1` may be more specific than you need. Or it might not specific enough if two `Schedule` elements were to have the same `value1` attribute. Instead, you can find the children `Program` elements by calling `schedule.xpath`:

```
schedule.xpath('ScheduleEvent/Program/@value2')
```

instead of starting over from the top of the tree using `tree.xpath`.

Comment: It looks like a tidy solution, but doesn't quite give me what I want.  I'm looking to get each 'value2' on a seperate line, for easier manipulation when it's imported into Excel.  I'll have a look at ebarr's solution above and try to get that working.  Thanks anyway - this will come in useful later on I think!

Comment: You don't need to use the grouper recipe, `zip(*[iter(values)]*3)`, if that's not what you want. Just print out `values`.

Answer (score 0):

A different method also using `lxml` would be:

```
import lxml.etree as et

message = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>       
<TVAMain>                                                 
    <ProgramDescription>                                  
        <ProgramLocationTable>                            
            <Schedule value1="1234">                      
                <ScheduleEvent>                           
                    <Program value2="1234567890" />       
                </ScheduleEvent>                          
                <ScheduleEvent>                           
                    <Program value2="1234567891" />       
                </ScheduleEvent>                          
            </Schedule>                                   
            <Schedule value1="5678">                      
                <ScheduleEvent>                           
                    <Program value2="1234567892" />       
                </ScheduleEvent>                          
                <ScheduleEvent>                           
                    <Program value2="1234567893" />       
                </ScheduleEvent>                          
            </Schedule>                                   
        </ProgramLocationTable>                           
    </ProgramDescription>                                 
</TVAMain>"""

tree = et.fromstring(message)
schedules = tree.xpath("ProgramDescription/ProgramLocationTable")[0].findall("Schedule")
for schedule in schedules:
    for event in schedule.findall("ScheduleEvent"):
        program = event.find("Program")
        print schedule.attrib["value1"],program.attrib["value2"]
```

this will print out:

```
1234 1234567890
1234 1234567891
5678 1234567892
5678 1234567893
```

Comment: I'm getting an error:   schedules = tree.find("ProgramLocationTable").findall("Schedule")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findall'.  It definately exists in the XML.  Any ideas?

Comment: That probably means that `tree.find("ProgramLocationTable")` is returning `None`. Is the XML you are using different from what you posted? I tried with your example and this works fine.

Comment: There was a discrepancy in my XML structure. I'd omitted the very top level tag 'TVAMain'.  I did a test, and adding this into the sample breaks the file I posted above.  Why is this?  Since ProgramLocationTable isn't in the very top level, why does not work?

Comment: I get the same error message.  To clarify: the actual XML already had 'TVAMain' in it (causing the error). My sample above was missing it however, so your helpful example worked.  Now that I've updated the sample, it errors as I was seeing (schedules = tree.find("ProgramLocationTable").findall("Schedule") AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findall'.)

Comment: @unutbu - Would either of you have any pointers on resolving this?  The extra 'top' level breaks it and I don't understand why.  Is there a way to set the 'root' of the find at the 'ProgramDescription' level?

Comment: @Nick the problems just appears to be that you need to explicitly state your paths to the first find. Do you still get a NoneType error with the above?